# Selecting in LINQ based on value in navigation property value

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have a list of vehicles that are in various categories..

```
public IList<Vehicle> GetAllByCat(int compId, short catId)
{
    var _vehicles = Context.Vehicle
        .Where(i => 
            i.CompanyId == compId && 
            i.VehicleCategories.Any(o => o.VehicleCategoryId == catId))
        .ToList();

    return _vehicles;
}
```

But it returns null (and I get an text in debug that `_vehicles` does not exists in current Context)

I have searched extensively for an answer but not found anything that helps. 
Any idea?

Comment: Where exactly are you getting the error? On the return?

Comment: That code won't return null from the `GetAllByCat` method. It will return, at worst, an empty list of vehicles. Please can you produce an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that accurately reproduces your issue?

Comment: You have to include the VehicleCategories first

Comment: @Valkyrie What do you mean, include. Should it not bee available trough navigation?

Comment: @IngimarAndresson no it doesn't see my answer. try it out tell me the result ty.

Comment: I get the error: CS01103: The name '_vehicles' does not exists in the current context

Comment: @Valkyrie How would you include the Categories in this query?

Comment: @IngimarAndresson Put a Break point on `var _vehicles` see if it's getting filled or not and as MindSwipe said at which line do you get the error? on return or ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188266/discussion-between-valkyrie-and-ingimar-andresson).

Comment: Check for `_vehicles` vs. `_Vehicles`.

Comment: You wrote: "I get a text in debug that _vehicles does not exists in current Context" Interesting, because `_vehicles` is not part of your LINQ statement. Are you sure about the error?  You also wrote: "But it returns null" Are you sure that `ToList` returns null? I can hardly imagine that. Consider editing your question such that you write the proper errors, and preferably also the significant parts of your classes

Answer (score 1):

You have to get the VehicleCategories first then you can use `Any` method on it. so one way would be using eager loading to get the related categories then search within them.

```
public IList<Vehicle> GetAllByCat(int compId, short catId)
{
    var _vehicles = Context.Vehicle
        .Include(x => x.VehicleCategories)
        .Where(i => 
            i.CompanyId == compId && 
            i.VehicleCategories.Any(o => o.VehicleCategoryId == catId))
        .ToList();

    return _vehicles;
}
```